# I graduated mid-intership, and now my stay has been extended. Should I ask for a payrise?

Tags: salary, work-experience

I am currently working as an engineering intern at a small power station. Originally, I was planning to stay here for 3 months to complete the work experience requirements of my degree and now that the 3 months is up, I have officially graduated with a BA of Engineering.

The plan was to start applying for graduate jobs once I had graduated but an opportunity has arose where I have agreed to develop a system for the power plant which will extend my stay by another 3 months.

I am currently working 5 days a week, 6-8 hours a day for an average of about 35ish hours a week and am paid by the hour.

My question is, now that I have graduated, is it reasonable for me to ask for a small payrise? Or am I still worth the same?

Comment: A "small raise" for two months of work is a small amount of money, and may involve a lot of bureaucracy. I think the moment to ask for a raise (trying to get to non-intern pay level) would be if they see your project finished and offer you more work.

Comment: @SJuan76 I'd say it's worth pushing for compensation in some way. That's abour 40 business days at 7 hours a day. 280 hours at the difference could be worthwhile. Even $3-4/hr more is another $500 per month.

Comment: There is difference between this question and the question linked above. The OP of this one is an intern for only 3 months. The OP of the other question is a regular employee for 2 years.

Comment: @SJuan76 The place is fairly casual with my employment and use an external payment system to process my wages. There would be very little, if any bureaucracy for the to deal with.

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a point that needs to be made. You're not an intern anymore, are you? So why should you accept the same wages?

If they want you to stay, they should make it worth your while to stay because what they're doing is preventing you from making the higher wages you would get that you suddenly aren't applying for.

If it were me, I'd start applying for the graduate jobs unless they can provide you a similar wage. Otherwise they're actually costing you money by preventing you from advancing in your career.

Comment: That's correct, technically I'm not an intern anymore as the time I originally agreed to inter in complete, and now I have my degree. The problem is, I already agreed (in words) to take on this new project with no mention of a payrise.

Answer (score 1):

> is it reasonable for me to ask for a small payrise?

Yes. Actually, I think you should go to see their Human Resources and submit your formal full time job application.

The reason is simple, you are not intern anymore. You already graduated. You are qualified to apply for a full time job.

This is a better way to tell them you want a pay raise. If they want you to continue to work there, they will have to consider offering you a formal full time job. At least, they will consider giving you a pay raise if they only want you work there as a part-timer.

Of course, there is a downside. If they only want a cheap labor, they'll just say you may leave now. In that case, it's probably not the place you want to stay. I would just leave and look for a job elsewhere if I were you.

Comment: I am not intending on staying past the conclusion of this new project, so I'm not going to apply for a full time position. They understand and are completely ok with this. The payrise was more to bring in just a fraction more cash over the next 2-3 months so I have a buffer in case there a period of unemployment between this job and my next one. I know they need me to complete this project as they are having major problems with what I am fixing, and an external contractor would be a significant cost to them.

Comment: @Loocid It looks like they just want cheap labor. I would just ask for pay raise if I were you. My answer is intended for not only you but also others with similar situation. However, I like to remind you two things. 1. You may not get the raise after you ask, because they just want cheap labor (this has nothing to do with your performance). 2. You will need to spend a lot time and energy when you are looking for a new job. You may have to go to different places for interviews. I doubt they may grant you the leave, they just want you to complete the project. Good luck for your job hunting!

Comment: @Loocid Also, verbal agreement does not mean anything! (in response to your another comment).

Comment: Very true. Thanks for your advice. I haven't started the project yet (still waiting on exact requirements), so I might see what I can do.